# mvc 4 template issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I installed MVC 4 for VS 2010 VS Express for Web (2012). No matter what version I use, my internet MVC 4 web application does not have all features as described by many bloggers. For example, login link is not showing login dialog but regular login page. In addition, I could not make jquery-ui dialog work (title is shifted to the right).

Before I dive into troubleshooting/debugging CSS/jscripts, I would like to make sure I am not missing something simple here ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can confirm this is the same with Visual Studio 2012 Premium. The "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application" project template doesn't generate the jQuery UI Dialog login popups.